# JS Regex - Match everything inside commas with a keyword

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to capture all occurence of "anytext *Player*" (player being the keyword) from a single line string.

```
testString = "Carpenter, Marketer, Yo-Yo Master, Kite Surfer, Baseball Player, Dentist, Football Player, Tax Man, Waterboy is not a player"
```

I've tried the following `(Baseball|Football)\sPlayer`, but this isn't dynamic.

Desired output = `"Baseball Player, Football Player, Waterboy is not a player"`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about "Player one" or anything else that doesn't end with the word "player" but that contains it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
\w[\s\w-]*\s[pP]layer\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IaHl6d/4)

**Code:**

```js
const testString = "Carpenter, Marketer, Yo-Yo Master, Kite Surfer, Baseball Player, Dentist, Football Player, Tax Man, Waterboy is not a player"

const re = /\w[\s\w-]*\s[pP]layer\b/g;

console.log(testString.match(re))
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\w`: Match a word character
- `[\s\w-]*`: Match 0 or more of word or whitespace or hyphen characters
- `\s`: Match 1 whitespace
- `[pP]layer\b`: Match word `Player` or `player`

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for providing the RegEx details! I need to study up on this :-) Again, much appreciated!

Comment: Nice and simple solution! It can be improved further by using word boundary i.e. `\w[\s\w-]*\s\b[pP]layer\b`.

Comment: Good point @ArvindKumarAvinash, editing it

Comment: What if I wanted to find the inverse of `\w[\s\w-]*\s\b[pP]layer\b` where it only return non-"Player"?

Comment: @NoobUser: You may use: `/(?<=,\s*)\w(?![\s\w-]*\s[pP]layer\b)[^,\n]*/g`

Comment: Wow... I was hoping for an easier != (not equals) trick. LOL. I did try what you suggested and I got: "Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 7" error. No idea what that means.

Comment: Try: `/(?<=,\s)\w(?![\s\w-]*\s[pP]layer\b)[^,\n]*/g`

Comment: Now it says "javax.script.ScriptException:<eval>:6:1/(?<=,\s)\w(?![\s\w-]*\s[pP]layer\b)[^,\n]* near index 1.

Comment: You can [see it is working here](https://regex101.com/r/IaHl6d/5)

Comment: It does work on RegEx101, but not on JS Nashorn :-(  Thank you so much for your response. Much appreciated.

Comment: ok then may be you can try: `\b\w(?!layer\b|[\s\w-]*\s[pP]layer\b)[^,\n]*`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Regex:

```
testString = "Carpenter, Marketer, Yo-Yo Master, Kite Surfer, Baseball Player, Dentist, Football Player, Tax Man, Waterboy is not a player"
var split = testString.split(',')

filtered = split.filter(s => s.toLowerCase().includes("player"))

var new_string = filtered .join(',')
```

Comment: splitting and filtering is a good idea, but you should split the string on `, ` instead of `,` and filter the string with: `/\bplayer\b/i.test(s)`

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte:  Above comment is unclear as it appears to say "comma instead of comma"  .... Perhaps quote marks around any spaces would be needed.

Comment: @JosephDoggie: I think talfreds isn't online because he's participating in a macarena competition and he's actually in semi-final. Other theory, talfreds that lives near the forest, was falling in love for a young female bear and decided to fly to Honolulu to surf with her. Note that this second theory doesn't exclude the first one.

Comment: That seems unlikely but you never know :)